# Is there any transparent deduplication for large binary data within PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, duplicates

We have an app which stores large binary data as large objects within a PostgreSQL database and now have a use case where we operate on that data in such a way that we know that parts of this already saved data will be saved once again only in slightly different combination. We are actually going to split some files and combine them in different ways, but want to preserve the original files additionally to the new combined ones.

This sounds like a good use case to consider deduplication. Are you aware of anything that works directly and transparent within Postgres, such that we don't need to re-invent the wheel? Something like a storage layer or plugin to add to Postgres so it handles deduplication on it's own for at least a whole database? Or maybe some library which works as a wrapper around the large object function of Postgres which our app could use and the wrapper lib does all the duplication part, maybe adds some tables for bookkeeping and all this stuff?

We are aware of filesystems with support for deduplication and one possibility could be to use those as the backend for Postgres' data storage. Another option would be to save the new data outside of Postgres within a deduplicating filesystem. But for now we would prefer something within Postgres which can be easily dumped and is backed by transactions etc.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is not (as of 9.4, anyway).

PostgreSQL compresses each individual item, but doesn't do any cross-item compression or deduplication.

The TOAST mechanism means that PostgreSQL should be able to deduplicate values in TOASTable types with some effort, it's just a matter of implementing it.

Patches are welcome ;-)